# Algorithm to find the minimum length of substring having all characters of other string

Tags: algorithm

I have a two strings: 
string1 - `hello how are you`, 
String2 - `olo` (including space character)

Output: `lo ho`   ( hel**lo ho**w are you )

`lo ho` is the only substring that contain all characters of string2.
Can anyone please suggest a good algorithm for this ( i can think og only Brute Force algo - O(n^2).

Also output should be the minimum length string(in case of multiple options).

Comment: Brute force is not `O(n^2)`, it is `O(n^3)` - checking each of the substrings is `O(n)` itself, and there are `O(n^2)` of those. Unless you had something else in mind?

Comment: should the output contain the space or without spaces as in original question?

Comment: @deathApril The output is the substring that contains all the characters, which includes the space in this case. It also includes the `h`.

Comment: I don't get your question... How does the two strings be verified by `lo ho`, because both the String1 and the output does not contain `olo`

Comment: and if we consider individual characters, then there are more than one outputs...

Comment: @NaveedButt The string "lo ho" is the smallest substring of `string1` whose multiset of characters is a superset of a multiset of the characters of `string2`. The statement "`lo ho` is the only substring that contain all characters of string2" from the question has to be a mistake, otherwise it makes no sense to me as well.

Answer (score 6):

Keep two pointer `l` and `r`, and a hash table `M = character -> count` for characters in string2 that do not occur in `s[l..r]`.

Initially set `l = 0` and `r` so that `string1[l..r]` contains all the characters of `string2` (if possible). You do that by removing characters from M until it is empty.

Then proceed by incrementing `r` by one in each step and then incrementing `l` as much as possible while still keeping M empty. The minimum over all `r - l + 1` (the length of the substring `s[l..r]`) is the solution.

Pythonish pseudocode:

```py
n = len(string1)
M = {}   # let's say M is empty if it contains no positive values
for c in string2:
    M[c]++
l = 0
r = -1
while r + 1 < n and M not empty:
    r++
    M[string1[r]]--
if M not empty: 
    return "no solution"
answer_l, answer_r = l, r
while True:
    while M[string1[l]] < 0:
        M[string1[l]]++
        l++
    if r - l + 1 < answer_r - anwer_l + 1:
        answer_l, answer_r = l, r
    r++
    if r == n:
        break
    M[string1[r]]--
return s[answer_l..answer_r]
```

The "is empty" checks can be implemented in O(1) if you maintain the number of positive entries when performing the increment and decrement operations.

Let `n` be the length of `string1` and `m` be the length of `string2`.

Note that `l` and `r` are only ever incremented, so there are at most O(n) increments and thus at most O(n) instructions are executed in the last outer loop.

If `M` is implemented as an array (I assume the alphabet is constant size), you get runtime
O(n + m), which is optimal. If the alphabet is too large, you can use a hash table to get expected O(n + m).

Example execution:

```
string1 = "abbabcdbcb"
string2 = "cbb"

# after first loop
M = { 'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 0 }

# after second loop
l = 0
r = 5
M = { 'a': -2, 'b': -1, 'c': 0, 'd': 0 }

# increment l as much as possible:
l = 2
r = 5
M = { 'a': -1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0 }

# increment r by one and then l as much as possible
l = 2
r = 6
M = { 'a': -1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': -1 }

# increment r by one and then l as much as possible
l = 4
r = 7
M = { 'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': -1 }

# increment r by one and then l as much as possible
l = 4
r = 8
M = { 'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': -1, 'd': -1 }

# increment r by one and then l as much as possible
l = 7
r = 9
M = { 'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0 }
```

The best solution is s[7..9].

Comment: wait.. at first I discarded the pseudocode as just over-simplified, but now I cannot see a way how to escape **O(n²)** worst case to make it return the correct solution? e.g. for OP's data, you cannot stop at `llho wo`, so `while M[string1[l]] < 0` is not enough, it needs to continue to the last `l`. another example `s1='abacccccbc'`, `s2='bc'` cannot stop at `bac` it needs to go all the way to `bc`, which will make the algorithm quadratic *(even if with good constant factors and it might be fast enough even for most cases of milions of characters)*.. or am I missing something?

Comment: @deathApril Both l and r are only ever incremented, never decremented, so the total number of loop iterations is O(n). I did not say you were supposed to stop somewhere, just try every possible `r`, so in your second example, you *will* at some point arrive at `s[l..r] = bc`. The trick is that the `l`s associated with increasing `r` are monotonically increasing.

Comment: I see, thanks. It also took me a while to wrap my mind around how `M` works, you could add comments like `# M = {o:2, l:1}` and # M = {h:-2, e: -1, l: -1, o: 0}` for illustrations..

Comment: oh, if the strings can by unicode, M is presumably better as defaultdict, not array..

Comment: @deathApril Well it depends. Technically the alphabet only has to be constant size, which is the case with Unicode. But of course you can use hash tables if you want to save space.

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate positions of characters from `string2` within `string1` and then pick the permutation with minimum distance between lowest and highest character position:

```py
#          positions are:
#          01234567890123456
string1 = 'hello how are you'
string2 = 'olo'

# get string1 positions for each character from set(string2)
positions = {'o': [4, 7, 15],
             'l': [2, 3]}

# get all permutations of positions (don't repeat the same element)
# then pick the permutation with minimum distance between min and max position
# (obviously, this part can be optimized, this is just an illustration)
permutations = positions['o'] * positions['l'] * positions['o']
permutations = [[4,2,7], [4,3,7], [4,2,15], ...]
the_permutation = [4,3,7]

# voilà
output = string1_without_spaces[3:7]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of implementation with JavaScript. The logic is similar as @Aprillion wrote above.

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ZB6vm/4/

```
var s1 = "hello how are you";
var s2 = "olo";
var left, right;
var min_distance;
var answer = "";

// make permutation recursively
function permutate(ar, arrs, k) {
    // check if the end of recursive call
    if (k == arrs.length) {
        var r = Math.max.apply(Math, ar);
        var l = Math.min.apply(Math, ar);
        var dist = r - l + 1;
        if (dist <= min_distance) {
            min_distance = dist;
            left = l;
            right = r;
        }
        return;
    }
    for (var i in arrs[k]) {
        var v = arrs[k][i];
        if ($.inArray(v, ar) < 0) {
            var ar2 = ar.slice();
            ar2.push(v);
             // recursive call
            permutate(ar2, arrs, k + 1);
        }
    }
}

function solve() {
    var ar = [];   // 1-demension array to store character position
    var arrs = []; // 2-demension array to store character position
    for (var i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
        arrs[i] = [];
        var c = s2.charAt(i);
        for (var k = 0; k < s1.length; k++) { // loop by s1
            if (s1.charAt(k) == c) {
                if ($.inArray(k, arrs[i]) < 0) {
                    arrs[i].push(k); // save position found
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // call permutate
    permutate(ar, arrs, 0);
    answer = s1.substring(left, right + 1);
    alert(answer);
}

solve();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is this algorithm which does this in O(N).

Idea: Have 2 arrays, viz. isRequired[256] and isFound[256] which tells the frequency of each character in S and while parsing the string S, the frequency of each character that has found yet. Also, keep a counter which tells when a valid window is found. Once a valid window is found, we can shift the window (towards right) maintaining the given invariant of the question.

Program in C++:

```
void findMinWindow(const char *text, const char *pattern, int &start, int &end){
        //Calcuate lengths of text and pattern
        int textLen = strlen(text);
        int patternLen = strlen(pattern);

        // Declare 2 arrays which keep tab of required & found frequency of each char in pattern
        int isRequired[256] ; //Assuming the character set is in ASCII
        int isFound[256];
        int count = 0; //For ascertaining whether a valid window is found

        // Keep a tab of minimum window 
        int minimumWindow = INT_MAX;

        //Prepare the isRequired[] array by parsing the pattern
        for(int i=0;i<patternLen;i++){
            isRequired[pattern[i]]++;
        }

        //Let's start parsing the text now
        // Have 2 pointers: i and j - both starting at 0
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        //Keep moving j forward, keep i fixed till we get a valid window
        for(c=j;c<textLen;c++){
           //Check if the character read appears in pattern or not
           if(isRequired[text[c]] == 0){
              //This character does not appear in the pattern; skip this
              continue;
           }
           //We have this character in the pattern, lets increment isFound for this char
           isFound[text[c]]++;

           //increment the count if this character satisfies the invariant
           if(isFound[text[c]] <= isRequired[text[c]]){
              count++;
           }

           //Did we find a valid window yet?
           if(count == patternLen){
              //A valid window is found..lets see if we can do better from here on
              //better means: increasing i to reduce window length while maintaining invariant
              while(isRequired[s[i]] == 0 || isFound[s[i]] > isRequired[s[i]]){
                   //Either of the above 2 conditions means we should increment i; however we 
                   // must decrease isFound for this char as well.
                   //Hence do a check again
                   if(isFound[s[i]] > isRequired[s[i]]){
                      isFound[s[i]]--;
                   }
                   i++;
              }

               // Note that after the while loop, the invariant is still maintained
               // Lets check if we did better
               int winLength = j-i+1;
               if(winLength < minimumWindow){
                  //update the references we got
                  begin = i;
                  end = j;
                  //Update new minimum window lenght
                  minimumWindow = winLength;
               }
          } //End of if(count == patternLen)
     } //End of for loop 
}
```