# Ruby programing Quiz

Tags: algorithm

Please help me in solving ruby program

Let us Suppose you have three strings say s1, s2 and s3.Now coding F(s1, s2, s3) should be shortest continuous subsequence of s1 such that it has all the chars of s2 and none of s3. 
s2 has uniq chars

For example: s1 = "peeeeloisagood", s2 = "le", s3 = "z". Ans = el

Comment: Share your own thoughts and attempts at solving the problem please

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951990/algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-length-of-substring-having-all-characters-of-other/23952655#23952655 can be adapted to your use case

Comment: Add a few more complex cases for unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it. (Don't be fooled by the fact that I posted before @AFaderDarkly, who has a similar answer. My original answer had a flaw.  When I noticed it, I deleted my answer and set about the repair. Darkly posted before I completed the fix, but I didn't know that until I undeleted my amended answer.)

**Code**

```
def find_it(s1,s2,s3)
  arr = s1.chars
  good = s2.chars
  bad = s3.chars    
  (good.size..arr.size).each { |n| arr.each_cons(n) { |c|
    return c.join if (good-c).empty? && (c-bad) == c } }
  nil
end
```

**Examples**

```
find_it("peeeeloisagood", "le", "z") #=> "el"
find_it("abcdezfherdzn", "def", "z") #=> "fherd"
```

**Explanation**

Let s1, s2 and s3 be as in the second example above:

```
s1 = "abcdezfherdzn"
s2 = "def"
s3 = "z"
```

We will first look at substrings of `s1` of length `2` (the size of `s2`). If we find one that contains all the letters of `s2`, we are finished (as it could not contain any letters of `s3`). If we do not find a match we look at substrings of `s1` of length `3`. We are finished if we find a substring that contains all the letters of `s2` and none of `s3`, and so on. If no substring of `s1` of any length contains all the letters of `s2` and none of the letters of `s3`, `nil` is returned.

```
arr = s1.chars
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "z", "f", "h", "e", "r", "d", "z", "n"]
good = s2.chars
  #=> ["d", "e", "f"]
bad = s3.chars    
  #=> ["z"]

enum1 = (good.size..arr.size).each
  #=>   (3..13).each
  #=>   #<Enumerator: 3..13:each>
```

We can convert an enumerator to an array to what it will be passing into its block:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

This enumerator first passes `3` into its block and assigns it to the block variable:

```
n = 3

enum2 = arr.each_cons(n)
  #=>   #<Enumerator: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "z", "f", "h",
  #                    "e", "r", "d", "z", "n"]:each_cons(3)> 
enum2.to_a
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["d", "e", "z"],
  #    ["e", "z", "f"], ["z", "f", "h"], ["f", "h", "e"], ["h", "e", "r"],
  #    ["e", "r", "d"], ["r", "d", "z"], ["d", "z", "n"]]
```

It first passes `["a", "b", "c"]` into the block and assigns it to the block variable:

```
c = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and executes

```
return c.join if (good-c).empty? && (c-bad) == c 
  #=> return "abc" if (["d", "e", "f"]-["a", "b", "c"]).empty? &&
  #                   (["a", "b", "c"] - ["z"]) == ["a", "b", "c"]
  #=> return "abc" if (["d", "e", "f"]).empty? && 
                      (["a", "b", "c"]) == ["a", "b", "c"]
  #=> return "abc" if false and true
  #=> false
```

This continues until the array `["d", "e", "z", "f"]` comes up, at which point we obtain:

```
return c.join if (good-c).empty? && (c-bad) == c 
  #=> return "dezf" if (["d", "e", "f"]-["d", "e", "z", "f"]).empty? &&
                       (["d", "e", "z", "f"]-["z"]) == ["d", "e", "z", "f"]
  #=> return "dezf" if [].empty? && ["d", "e", "f"] == ["d", "e", "z", "f"]
  #=> return "dezf" if true && false
  #=> false
```

so we reject that substring as well, this time because of the presence of `z`.

When we get to

```
c = ["f", "h", "e", "r", "d"]
```

we obtain:

```
 return c.join if (good-c).empty? && (c-bad) == c 
   #=> return "fherd" if (["d", "e", "f"]-["f", "h", "e", "r", "d"]).empty? &&
                (["f", "h", "e", "r", "d"]-["z"]) == ["f", "h", "e", "r", "d"]
   #=> return "fherd" if [].empty? &&
                 ["f", "h", "e", "r", "d"] == ["f", "h", "e", "r", "d"]
   #=>return "fherd" if true && true
```

and therefore return `"fherd"`.

Comment: Thanks, @AFaderDarkly, but I'm not naturally a neat purpose.  I was just responding to having been called a messy person for many, many years.

Comment: By the way, my answer also had a flaw or two on first posting. I think you settled down to your final answer first...

Answer (score 1):

```
search_string = s1.gsub(/^[^#{s2}]+|[^#{s2}]+$/, '')
```

The shortest string containing all of s2 will always start and end with a character from s2, so this reduces the search space.

```
included = s2.chars.to_a.uniq
excluded = s3.chars.to_a.uniq
input = search_string.chars.to_a
```

This just makes things easier to deal with - all are converted to arrays. We run uniq over the included and excluded arrays to catch edge cases and optimise the algorithm.

Now we can scan through the string, brute-force style:

```
(included.length..search_string.length).each do |l|
```

The shortest string can only be as short as the set of included characters, so we set up a search window moving through the string, starting at this length and moving up to the full length of the string. l is the window length.

```
    input.each_cons(l) do |s|
```

Move the window through the input array.

```
      if (included - s).length == 0 && excluded == excluded - s
```

Check if the string matches by subtracting arrays.

```
      puts s.join
```

This will show all matches, shortest first.

```
    end
  end
end
```

Putting it all together:

```
def find_string(s1, s2, s3)
  search_string = s1.gsub(/^[^#{s2}]+|[^#{s2}]+$/, '')
  included = s2.chars.to_a.uniq
  excluded = s3.chars.to_a.uniq
  input = search_string.chars.to_a

  (included.length..search_string.length).each do |l|
    input.each_cons(l) do |s|
      if (included - s).length == 0 && excluded == excluded - s
        return s.join
      end
    end
  end
  ""
end   

find_string  "pleeeesoisalzesgood", "les", "z"
# => "leeees"

find_string  "pleeeesoisalesgood", "les", "z"
# => "les"

find_string  "pleeeesoisalesgood", "lees", "z" # Without the .uniq on included this would return 'sale'
# => "les" 

find_string  "peeeeloisagood", "le", "z"
# => "el"
```

Comment: Wow, our methods are nearly the same. (I didn't look at your answer when doing edits--really.) I like your first line, which I didn't think of. (In a now-deleted comment I said the first line was "brilliant", but I had misunderstood; it's merely nice.) +1.

Comment: Yeah, brilliant would be removing the nested loop, but thanks. :)

Comment: You don't need `to_a` in `chars.to_a`. No reply please, as I'll delete this comment once you've seen it...

Comment: You're obviously using Ruby 2.x. In 1.9.x `chars` yields an enumerator. In order to ensure maximum compatibility, a little `.to_a` isn't going to break the bank. no need to delete. :)